# How can I remove the first child (.item) and append it to the end with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, slider, product, appendchild, removechild

I need to **remove the first .item** in the #slide element and **append it to the end** of .item elements. Need a **pure JavaScript** solution.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
    </div>
    <button class="ctrl-btn pro-prev disabled">Prev</button>
    <button class="ctrl-btn pro-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

I have **found this snippet and tried to use**. But failed.

```
for (let i = 0; i < slides.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (slides.childNodes[i].tagName == 'IMG') {
        slides.removeChild(slides.childNodes[i]);
        slides.appendChild(slides.childNodes[slides.childNodes.length - 1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: what is variable slides in the code snippet you found at some undisclosed place, (so, still haven't tried anything),  where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0];
var firstChild = slide.children[0];
slide.appendChild(firstChild);
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product100">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product1">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product2">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
        <img class="item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Product3">
    </div>
    <button class="ctrl-btn pro-prev disabled">Prev</button>
    <button class="ctrl-btn pro-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your third line should be like this //slide.removeChild(slide.children[0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
 var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0];
 slide.appendChild(slide.children[0]);
```

Comment: Please provide some description to your answer to make it readable/understandable by others.